# Remove div from container and wrap it over the container using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some wordpress content on which I am creating a filter so that it does something like this. 
Below is the source html text that is generated by wordpress :

```
<div id="attachment_210" style="width: 1076px" class="wp-caption alignnone">
<div class="the-image">
    <img class="wp-image-210 size-full" src="http://localhost/tiphaine/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1IMG_0582.jpg" alt="IMG_0582" width="1066" height="1600" />
</div>
<p class="wp-caption-text">
    <span class="top-right white">
        sweater //
        <a href="#">Calvin Klein via Zalando</a>
        <br />
        skirt //
        <a href="#">Gesutz (similar)</a>
        <br />
        bag //
        <a href="#">Burberry via Monnier Frères (budget)</a>
        <br />
        slip ons //
        <a href="#">Ash (similar)</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Now if you notice, there is `div class="the-image"` wrapped over the `img` tag. 
I want to remove this wrapper from there and wrap the whole content with itself. So the final result becomes like this :

```
<div class="the-image">
    <div id="attachment_210" style="width: 1076px" class="wp-caption alignnone">
        <img class="wp-image-210 size-full" src="http://localhost/tiphaine/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1IMG_0582.jpg" alt="IMG_0582" width="1066" height="1600" />
        <p class="wp-caption-text">
            <span class="top-right white">
                sweater //
                <a href="#">Calvin Klein via Zalando</a>
                <br />
                skirt //
                <a href="#">Gesutz (similar)</a>
                <br />
                bag //
                <a href="#">Burberry via Monnier Frères (budget)</a>
                <br />
                slip ons //
                <a href="#">Ash (similar)</a>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="the-image">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-209" src="http://localhost/tiphaine/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2IMG_0337.jpg" alt="IMG_0337" width="1066" height="1600" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not very good with regular expressions so had to ask it here.

Comment: do u have the answer, sir?

Comment: That sounds like a hack what you want to do. Do you have the ability to alter your template files?